# Relacionar dataframes por coincidencia

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supongamos que tenemos dos dataframes

```
df1= pd.DataFrame(np.array([["Bogota"], ["Sevilla"], ["Venecia"],["Madrid"]]),
               columns=['Ciudad'])
df2= pd.DataFrame(np.array([["Bogota - Cali - Medellin - Pasto - Bucaramanga", "Colombia"],\
                            ["Dijon - Paris - Marsella - Estrasburgo","Francia"], ["Birmingham - Londres - Hastings", "Inglaterra"],\
                            ["Roma - Turim - Bari - Venecia - Florencia","Italia"],["Buenos Aires - Mendoza - Rosaro - Bariloche","Argentina"],\
                            ["Madrid - Barcelona - Valencia - Sevilla","España"]]),
                   columns=['Ciudades', 'Pais'])
```

Lucen así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber cómo puedo relacionar la columna "Ciudad" del dataframe 1 con la columna "Ciudades " del dataframe 2, teniendo en cuenta que no tienen los mismos registros sino que una está contenida en la otra. Lo que se desea es que se cree una nueva columna que asigne al df1 el país que le corresponde a cada ciudad teniendo en cuenta la información de df2.
Es decir, que muestre algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos maneras de llegar al `DataFrame` final, mi conocimiento de `pandas` es mínimo.

La primera es utilizando [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Consiste en iterar el maestro de Ciudades, `df1`, y generar un `DataFrame` reducido, cada vez que una ciudad se encuentre dentro de `df2['Ciudades']`.
Cada coincidencia la guardaremos en una lista `data`, el registro que nos interesa guardar será la ciudad y el pais. El `if` está preguntando si hubo coincidencias, de ser así... se guardará.

```
data = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    
    aux = df2[df2['Ciudades'].str.contains(row['Ciudad'])]
    if len(aux) > 0:
        data.append([row['Ciudad'],
                     aux['Pais'].iloc[0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['Ciudad','Pais'])

df
```

output:

```
    Ciudad  Pais
0   Bogota  Colombia
1   Sevilla España
2   Venecia Italia
3   Madrid  España
```

2. Opción:

También podemos ayudarnos de una `list comprehension` para resolver el problema. Ésta consiste en recorrer `df2['Ciudades']` pero utilizando `.split('-')` (ya que es el separador de ciudades). Entonces ahora estaríamos iterando cada Ciudad de df2, y guardaremos el Pais. En pocas palabras estamos abriendo `df2` por `Pais`.
El resultado lo guardamos en una lista `data`, y creamos un nuevo `DataFrame` `df3`.  Ahora que ya tenemos `df3` con una apariencia similar a `df1`, podemos utilizar [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.merge) para cruzar los dos dfs por el campo Ciudad

```
data = [[ciudad.strip(),row['Pais']] for index, row in df2.iterrows() for ciudad in row['Ciudades'].split('-')]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns = ['Ciudad','Pais'] )


df3
>>>

   
    Ciudad          Pais
0   Bogota          Colombia
1   Cali            Colombia
2   Medellin        Colombia
3   Pasto           Colombia
4   Bucaramanga     Colombia
5   Dijon           Francia
6   Paris           Francia
7   Marsella        Francia
8   Estrasburgo     Francia
9   Birmingham      Inglaterra
10  Londres         Inglaterra
11  Hastings        Inglaterra
12  Roma            Italia
13  Turim           Italia
14  Bari            Italia
15  Venecia         Italia
16  Florencia       Italia
17  Buenos Aires    Argentina
18  Mendoza         Argentina
19  Rosaro          Argentina
20  Bariloche       Argentina
21  Madrid          España
22  Barcelona       España
23  Valencia        España
24  Sevilla         España


df = pd.merge(df3,df1,on='Ciudad')
df
>>>
    Ciudad  Pais
0   Bogota  Colombia
1   Venecia Italia
2   Madrid  España
3   Sevilla España
```

pd: Cuando se utiliza pandas, no se recomienda el uso de `.iterrows()`, siempre es mejor tratar de evitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede optar por una solución mucho más simplificada usando solo una función y haciendo un procesamiento a los datos del primer DataFrame que contiene toda la información.

Primero tendremos que convertir el string que contiene las ciudades a una lista para que cada elemento represente una ciudad, para ello podemos usar el método `.apply()` de los dataframes y series para que apliquen una operación especifica a fila por fila.

```py
df2["Ciudades"] = df2["Ciudades"].apply(lambda x: [e.strip() for e in x.split("-")])
print(df2)
```

Que nos retorna:

|  | Ciudades | Pais |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [Bogota, Cali, Medellin, Pasto, Bucaramanga] | Colombia |
| 1 | [Dijon, Paris, Marsella, Estrasburgo] | Francia |
| 2 | [Birmingham, Londres, Hastings] | Inglaterra |
| 3 | [Roma, Turim, Bari, Venecia, Florencia] | Italia |
| 4 | [Buenos Aires, Mendoza, Rosaro, Bariloche] | Argentina |
| 5 | [Madrid, Barcelona, Valencia, Sevilla] | España |

Como ya lo tenemos en una lista se nos facilitará saber si una ciudad está contenida en ese lista usando la sintaxis `elemento in iterable`.

Ahora lo que he hecho ha sido crear una función para saber obtener el país al que pertenece la ciudad, esto haciendo uso nuevamente del método `.apply()` y usando una *list comprehension*

```py
def search_pais(ciudad, df):
    return [pais for pais in df.apply(lambda row: row["Pais"] if ciudad in row["Ciudades"] else None, axis=1) if pais][0]
```

A esta función se le pasan 2 parámetros, el primero es la ciudad a buscar y el segundo es el dataframe en el cual buscar. Luego usamos el método `apply()` para poder aplicar la función a cada fila. El `.apply()` retorna el nombre del país si es que la ciudad se encuentra en la lista de ciudades (por eso se convirtió a lista), en caso no esté retorna `None`. Sin embargo `apply` retorna una Serie con todos los resultados de la columna, pero a nosotros solo nos interesa la fila que contiene el nombre del país, para ello eliminamos todos los `None` con una *list comprehension*.

Ahora solo nos queda crear una nueva columna en el `df1` donde irá el resultado de aplicar la función `search_pais` a cada fila, nuevamente usaremos `.apply()`

```py
df1["Pais"] = df1["Ciudad"].apply(lambda ciudad: search_pais(ciudad, df2))
print(df1)
```

Y nos retorna:

|  | Ciudad | Pais |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bogota | Colombia |
| 1 | Sevilla | España |
| 2 | Venecia | Italia |
| 3 | Madrid | España |

Comment: Usé ambos aportes, la verdad funcionan perfecto, gracias.

Comment: En ese caso es difícil marcar como aceptada una respuesta :/